# Jasper Studio Community Edition: Expression Editor is not showing all the expressions

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

In my jasper studio 6.21.2, i'm able to see expression editor appears as below for some of the jrxml files.
[expression editor working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiL4e.jpg)

For some of the jrxmls, it is coming like this. Not sure what's wrong.
[expression editor not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bKEr.jpg)

is there anything missed?

I tried reinstalling the jasper studio 6.22.2 and tried importing the same project. But still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your posted images, in the first you're using a Java editor, in the second image you're using a Javascript, so the view are bit differents.

Please use the Java editor for your formulas, so you can the full control about all usable objects.

Pay attention, you can embed the images and pictures in the question, instead of use an external link.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

All started working without any issues after restarting my system.  Not sure why i was getting java script editor instead of java editor.  But one observation was same java editor was working properly for other report design in the same project, only for couple of reports, this issue was coming where it was opening java script editor.